# How to prevent Yandex metrics from loading on Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, yandex, yandex-metrika

There is a script inside head block of my website that I don't want to load. It does not belong to any plugin, this is Yandex metrics. I don't want it. Is there any way to prevent this script from adding?

Comment: Well, if you haven't installed the yandex plugin that's definitely weird. Maybe a theme or plugin doing things it's not supposed to.
Did you disable all plugin by plugin to check if it still loads? (to figure out which plugin is loading it).  Second: if you switch theme, it still loads?

You might also try to check all enqueued scripts.
https://lakewood.media/list-enqueued-scripts-handle/
But i suspect it's not being enqueued properly

Comment: Yes - I still have it when disable all plugins. No - I don't have it when activating new theme. But I wrote that theme from scratch and never added Yandex to it

Comment: I've found that Google Tag Manager adds Yandex. Apparently I should set it somewhere in Google Analytics settings or something. So I guess it's impossible to block third party scripts add another scripts in runtime?